# pass object from servlet to another java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have a mini JEE app that have two views: Form to sign up then another jsp to display all users signed-up.
I created the two jsp files: Form for the first and table to the second.
I also created two servlets one for the first jsp and other for the second.
when I submit informations (name,email,phone and message)from the first view I could get it from the 1st servlet then display it again to the jsp1, so I am sure now that I successfully could get data from jsp form as a user object.
My issue is I don't know how to display all users in the second jsp by using servlet2 and javabean2
the first servlet:

```
package com.TP.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.TP.beans.SaisieBean;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Saisie
 */
@WebServlet("/Saisie")
public class Saisie extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Saisie() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/saisiedemande/index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SaisieBean user = new SaisieBean();
        
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String message = request.getParameter("message");
        
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPhone(phone);
        user.setMessage(message);
        
        //request.setAttribute("user", user);
        //this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/recherchedemande/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/saisiedemande/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

the first javaBean:

```
 package com.TP.beans;

public class SaisieBean {
    private String name;
    private String email; 
    private String phone;
    private String message;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    
    
}
```

Thank's for providing me with a solution for my problem

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have set the user object in the session. If I understand, you want to show the list of users in jsp page. If yes, you can create a List(ArrayList or LinkedList) and save it in the Session or context scope.

Now you can get the list in servlet where you are creating the user object and add this user object to your list.

On your JSP page, you can use JSTL to iterate through this list from context.